# mixed contents admin panel is Unsecured

Tags: wp-admin, errors, https, http

below link is causing mixed content url errors which gives wp-admin insecure warnings, I want to change this URL **http** to **https**

**I unable to find where this url is being called from**

`<html class="wp-toolbar” xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml” lang=”en-US">`

Answer (score 0):

That should not effect wp-admin, I have never seen that happen before. Are you sure both your site url and homepage url's are set to https://

If you really want to change them to see if that is the issue, you could edit them in the following files: (there are multiple mentions of that url in some of them)

```
/wp-admin/includes/template.php
/wp-admin/maint/repair.php
/wp-admin/setup-config.php
/wp-admin/install.php
/wp-admin/upgrade.php
```

I will be very surprised if that is your issue.

Comment: actually the problem was in white label CMS i change old http icon  link to https and problem solved

Comment: thanks @Elgoot's

Comment: i did not think that would be the issue. its not a physical resource being downloaded but more so a deceleration. good to know you found the actual issue  :)